# multisite authentication with .passport server

Tags: php, mysql

If anyone can help me I'm not sure what my SQL database should look like for the following PHP class.

```
http://realsauce.mirrors.phpclasses.org/package/4874-PHP-Manage-accounts-of-users-of-multiple-sites.html

http://www.phpclasses.org/package/4875-PHP-Authenticate-users-in-a-remote-server.html
```

my site is currently http://bid4bank.com/passport
I have created a table called users with the following
ID (Primary, auto increment)
user
pass
email
site

Or if you know of any other authentication servers that a more feature rich?